# how to show current month based on the year in drop down list using java script or java program

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a drop down list for month and year in my certificate.jsp page. I have to show the month based on the year which is selected by user. For example, if 2014 is selected in the year drop down, I should show 'January' in my month drop down and if 2013 is selected, I should show all the months.

```
<div class="width2 margin-bottom margin-top">
    <div class="profile-text">
        <span class="red">*</span>&nbsp;Certified On
    </div>
    <div class="profile-right">
        <s:select list="#{'':'--select month--','Jan':'Jan','Feb':'Feb','Mar':'Mar','Apr':'Apr','May':'May','Jun':'Jun','July':'July','Aug':'Aug','Sep':'Sep','Oct':'Oct','Nov':'Nov','Dec':'Dec'}" name="month" id="month" cssStyle="height:32px; width:48%;"   placeholder="Month" cssClass="profile-input "  headerValue="---Exp in Year---"/> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;              
        <s:select list="yearList" name="year" id="year" headerKey="" headerValue="--select year--" cssStyle="height:32px; width:48%;" placeholder="Year" cssClass="profile-input"></s:select>        
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `(new Date()).getMonth()+1` would give you the current month(1 for Jan, 2 for Feb, and so on) [Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth). You can use this to hide/show the desired months

Comment: Are you still looking for help with this?

Comment: no. I don't want that. I've done that